# Return Array of Column Names if Index is True (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, boolean-logic

I have a SQL Server table in the following form (data type is Bit):

```
role  |  column_1  |  column_2  |  column_3
------+------------+------------+-----------
a     |  True      |  True      |  False
b     |  True      |  False     |  True
c     |  False     |  False     |  True
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Roles
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'column_1' = 1)
             (SELECT 'column_2' = 1)
             (SELECT 'column_3' = 1)
```

However, this seems to return values 3 separate times.

How can I return the column names for a given role (ideally in a consolidated array) if the index is true?

For example:

- For role a, return `column_1` and `column_2`
- For role b, return `column_1` and `column_3`
- For role c, return `column_2` and `column_3`

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have an array column type. You could return a comma delimited list of true column names as a string but that is not a good approach. Why can't you construct the array in your client code?

Comment: Perhaps if you provide the desired results.

Comment: It would be a security risk to return all column names.

Comment: What is the topology here? You have untrusted code calling SQL Server with no intermediate layer?

Comment: Essentially returning a list of permissions.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is more maintainable to have a table of Booleans than to have a list of permissions in a single index.

Comment: The application loads more applications based on the user role.

Comment: Why is returning a comma delimited list of true column names as a string not a good approach?

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea. You leave this sort of string manipulation to the client. But that was before the explanation that the column names themselves can't be returned to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure based on suggestions from John Cappelletti.

Input table name, column name, filter

Returns filter index  |  column name |  column value

```
-- filterTableWithString
Alter Procedure [dbo].[filterTableWithString] 
@table as VarChar(50),
@column as VarChar(50),
@filter as VarChar(50),
@string as VarChar(max)

As

Declare @ssql NVarChar(max)

Select @ssql = 
'Select ' + @column +', c.*

  From' + QUOTENAME(@table) + 'a 
  Cross Apply (Values (Cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
  Cross Apply (
    Select Field = a.value(''local-name(.)'',''VarChar(max)''), 
    Value = a.value(''.'',''VarChar(max)'') 
    From  B.XMLData.nodes(''/row'')  as C1(n)
    Cross Apply C1.n.nodes(''./@*'') as C2(a)
    Where a.value(''local-name(.)'',''VarChar(max)'') Not In (''ExcludeOther'')
  ) C
Where ' + @column + ' = ''' + @filter + ''' 
And Cast(c.value as VarChar(max)) Like ( ''' + @string +''')'

Exec sp_executesql @ssql
```

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts.  You may gain some performance if you move your final WHERE into Cross Apply C.   Rather than using dynamic SQL, I created a Table-Valued-Function to create an EAV structure for virtually any table or record.  I'll post in a second answer.  Finally, since you are using dynamic SQL here, you might as well forego XML portion entirely and just construct a more natural SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments.

**Simple approach** if you don't mind listing the fields

```
Select Role
      ,Roles = stuff(
               replicate(',column_1',column_1)
              +replicate(',column_2',column_2)
              +replicate(',column_3',column_3)
              ,1,1,'')
 From  Roles
```

**Or if you want a more dynamic approach**

**Example**

```
Select A.Role
      ,C.*
 From Roles A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
               Select Roles = Stuff((Select ','+Field 
                                       From (
                                                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                                                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                                                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                                                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                                                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('role','ExcludeOther')
                                                   and a.value('.','varchar(max)') ='1'
                                            ) C1
                                       For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
             ) C
```

**Both Would Return**

```
Role    Roles
a       column_1,column_2
b       column_1,column_3
c       column_3
```

Comment: `case when col1=1 then ',col1' else '' end` could be replaced with `REPLICATE(',col1',col1)` potentially here as slightly more concise.

Comment: @MartinSmith Huh!  Brilliant!  Never occured to me.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll make the edit

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I started a ```community wiki``` for an extensible stored procedure based on your concepts.  I am new to SQL, so please let me know if modifications should be made.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Matthew I'll take a harder look later tonight.  At first glance looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this a lot harder than it needs to be. And in your subqueries you are comparing a string literal to an int which will always fail. Pretty sure you just need to use a couple of predicates here.

```
SELECT *
FROM Roles
WHERE column_1 = 1
    AND column_2 = 1
    AND column_3 = 1
```

Comment: I'm not trying to return if all conditions are true, just the conditions that are true.

Comment: e.g. For role a, return ```column_1``` and ```column_2```.  For role b return ```column_1``` and ```column_3```

Comment: Ugh...I understand what you are saying now. A better data model would make this a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here is my "dynamic" EAV function.   You can pass a record or entire table (avoid large tables).

To be clear, this is a helper function used to "dynamically" unpivot smaller tables or selected records within a CROSS APPLY.

Just a note, the first field in the query must be your Entity.

**Example of Table**

```
Declare @User table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com'),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Select * From [dbo].[tvf-EAV]((Select * From @User for XML RAW))
```

**Returns**

```
Entity  Attribute   Value
1       Active      1
1       First_Name  John
1       Last_Name   Smith
1       EMail       john.smith@email.com
2       Active      0
2       First_Name  Jane
2       Last_Name   Doe
2       EMail       jane.doe@email.com
```

**Example of ROW via Cross Cross Apply**

```
Declare @User table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50))
Insert into @User values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com'),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com')

Select A.EMail
      ,B.* 
 From  @User A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-EAV]((Select A.* for XML RAW)) B
 Where Active=1
```

**Returns**

```
EMail                   Entity  Attribute   Value
john.smith@email.com    1       Active      1
john.smith@email.com    1       First_Name  John
john.smith@email.com    1       Last_Name   Smith
john.smith@email.com    1       EMail       john.smith@email.com
```